# Run action from library

Tags: html, angular, rxjs, store, ngrx

I have an npm library, which contains an NGRX Action with an effect. How do I call it in my own application? Currently nothing happens, once I use store.dispatch().

Or maybe how should the action be exported, so I can access it with my store?

Comment: https://ngrx.io/guide/store

Answer (score 1):

Consider, Exporting all the actions from the library in to index.ts file of library module. Hence when importing your library via app.module of your app, you will have access to actions files of library in your components.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import the library module in your `.module.ts` file.